# jQuery remove nested ul/li

Tags: jquery

How do I use jQuery to delete all the elements under "li_1" (but not delete li_1)

```
<ul id="ul_1">
   <li id="li_1">1.1    //want to delete all its child elements
      <ul id="ul_1.1">    
          <li id="li_1.1.1">1.1.1</li>
          <li id="li_1.1.2">1.1.2
              <ul id="ul_1.1.2">
                 <li id="li_1.1.2.1">1.1.2.1</li>
                 <li id="li_1.1.2.2">1.1.2.2</li>
              </ul>
          </li> 
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="li_2">1.2</li>
   <li id="li_3">1.3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you know that this HTML isn't valid, right? Meaning the browser may not interpret as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is incorrect, You should change your markup something like below,

```
<ul id="ul_1">
   <li id="li_1">1.1    //want to delete all its child elements
      <ul id="ul_1.1">    
          <li id="li_1.1.1">1.1.1</li>
          <li id="li_1.1.2">1.1.2</li>
              <ul id="ul_1.1.2">
                 <li id="li_1.1.2.1">1.1.2.1</li>
                 <li id="li_1.1.2.2">1.1.2.2</li>
              </ul>
      </ul>
   </li>               // <-- Moved your sublist #ul_1.1 inside the li #li_1
   <li id="li_2">1.2</li>
   <li id="li_3">1.3</li>
</ul>
```

And change your JS as,

```
$('#li_1 ul').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

May be your markup has a bug. Actually the ul which you are referring is not a child of `li_1`. First fix the mark and try this code to delete all its children using `empty` method which removes all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Markup change

```
<ul id="ul_1">
   <li id="li_1">1.1  //want to delete all its child elements
      <ul id="ul_1.1">    
          <li id="li_1.1.1">1.1.1</li>
          <li id="li_1.1.2">1.1.2
              <ul id="ul_1.1.2">
                 <li id="li_1.1.2.1">1.1.2.1</li>
                 <li id="li_1.1.2.2">1.1.2.2</li>
              </ul>
           </li>
      </ul>
   </li>  
   <li id="li_2">1.2</li>
   <li id="li_3">1.3</li>
</ul>
```

Js

```
$('#li_1').empty();//will empty everything from this li element
```

If you just want to remove the child `ul` then try this

```
$('#li_1 > ul').remove();
```

Comment: Empty would also remove his '1.1', I think OP wants to remove the ul under the li #1.1. However his markup is incorrect and the sublist should be inside the main li#1.1.

Comment: @Lagoona: The only valid child of a `ul` is an `li`. You have `ul`s as children of a `ul`, which is incorrect. You must put the sub-unordered lists *inside* the list items they belong. Simply indenting it doesn't make it a child.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - Yes thats correct that is another bug in OP's markup.

Comment: @SKS - The element is still present, you don't see it because there is not content after call `empty` method. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/4Cm7e/1/ where I have added new content after emptying it.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: I know it doesn't remove the li. .empty simply sets your innerHTMl = ''. Probably you should add that in your answer about inserting new content after emptying it.. Why not just do $('#li_1 ul').remove();

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing out the markup errors. i've corrected them. (too much copy-paste)

Comment: @SKS - You can do that as well.

Comment: why do you guys/gals refer me as 'his'? LOL

Comment: Programmers are all male chauvinists ;). 99.9% of us *are* male, so when you don't know the gender "his" is a safe bet, but it'd be great to have more gals in our ranks ;).

Answer (score 0):

Your `li_1` element does not have any child as we can clearly see. If you want to remove `<ul id="ul_1.1">` you can simply use `$('#ul_1.1').remove();`. It will remove this element and all of its children (actually they are part of the element).

You can use some automatization. For example if you have `id` of this `li` element, then you can write `$('#'+id).next().remove();`.

If this is a bug in your HTML, then see ShankarSangoli answer.

Comment: in the real situation, i dont know the id ...i loop thru the tree struct and can only refer to ele using $(this)